# a word/phrase to refer to say bye

Tags: vocabulary

An English class just started, classmates say something like this

> How are you? I'm good. How about you?

The sentences are called **greetings**.

Suppose the class is closed/finished in a few minutes, classmates say something like these

> "Bye, see ya tomorrow."

> "We had fun today. See you next week!"

I guess the sentences above are neither **farewell** nor **greetings**, which word/phrase could be used to refer to them?

Comment: Why aren't `Bye, see ya tomorrow` and `See you next week!` farewells?

Comment: @pipinstallfrisbee It seems that "farewell" usually is used in an email by an employee not work for the company anymore, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are actually both farewells. “See you” in that context is shorthand for saying “I’ll next see you”. Socially, it’s courteous in that it lets them know that we’re thinking of them and looking forward to when we’ll next see them. If we’ll be continuing to see them now it doesn’t make sense to state when we’ll next be seeing them.

Comment: It seems that "farewell" usually is used in an email by an employee not work for the company anymore, right?

Comment: @PutBere In what sense? Do you mean the actual word “farewell”?